# Does Firebase AB testing use target user conditions for test devices?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I have set firebase AB test while for target user condition is set an user property. Now I wonder why are my test devices getting preset variants despite they are not matching the condition based on user property they send.

Are those testing devices excluded from evaluating of those conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that until is the AB test in draft (not started) you have no way how to test if those conditions for targeting are correct, only that device in test group (with given IID_TOKEN) receive preset variant.